# Drill - Parquet IO performance issues with Azure Blob or Azure Files

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, parquet, apache-drill, azure-storage-files

### The problem:

- Parquet read performance of Drill appears to be 5x - 10x worse when reading from azure storage and it renders it unusable for bigger data workloads.
- It appears to be only a problem when reading parquets. Reading CSV, at the other hand, runs normally.

---

### Let's have:

- Azure Blob storage account with ~1GB source.csv and parquets with same data.
- Azure **Premium** File Storage with the same files
- Local disk folder containing the same files
- Drill running on Azure VM in single mode

Drill configuration:

- Azure blob storage plugin working as namespace `blob`
- Azure files mounted with SMB to /data/dfs used as namespace `dfs`
- Local disk folder used as namespace `local`

The VM

- Standard E4s v3 (4 vcpus, 32 GiB memory)
- 256GB SSD
- NIC 2Gbps
- 6400 IOPS / 96MBps

Azure Premium Files Share

- 1000GB
- 1000 IOPS base / 3000 IOPS Burst
- 120MB/s throughput

---

### Storage benchmarks

- Measured with `dd`, 1GB data, various block sizes, conv=fdatasync
- FS cache dropped before each read test (`sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"`)

#### Local disk

```wiki
+-------+------------+--------+
| Mode  | Block size | Speed  |
+-------+------------+--------+
| Write |       1024 | 37MB/s |
| Write |         64 | 16MBs  |
| Read  |       1024 | 70MB/s |
| Read  |         64 | 44MB/s |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

#### Azure Premium File Storage SMB mount

```wiki
+-------+------------+---------+
| Mode  | Block size |  Speed  |
+-------+------------+---------+
| Write |       1024 | 100MB/s |
| Write |         64 | 23MBs   |
| Read  |       1024 | 88MB/s  |
| Read  |         64 | 40MB/s  |
+-------+------------+---------+
```

#### Azure Blob

*Max known throughput of azure blobs is 60MB/s. Upload/download speeds are clamped to target storage read/write speeds.*

---

### Drill benchmarks

- The filesystem cache was purged before every read test.
- IO performance observed with `iotop`
- Queries were chosen simple only for demonstration. Execution time growth for more complex queries is linear.

#### Sample queries:

```sql
-- Query A: Reading parquet
select sum(`Price`) as test from namespace.`Parquet/**/*.parquet`;

-- Query B: Reading CSV
select sum(CAST(`Price` as DOUBLE)) as test from namespace.`sales.csv`;
```

#### Results

```wiki
+-------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------+
|    Query    | Source (namespace) | Duration | Disk read usage |
+-------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------+
| A (Parquet) | dfs(smb)           | 14.8s    | 2.8 - 3.5 MB/s  |
| A (Parquet) | blob               | 24.5s    | N/A             |
| A (Parquet) | local              | 1.7s     | 40 - 80 MB/s    |
| ---         | ---                | ---      | ---             |
| B (CSV)     | dfs(smb)           | 22s      | 30 - 60 MB/s    |
| B (CSV)     | blob               | 29s      | N/A             |
| B (CSV)     | local              | 18s      | 68 MB/s         |
+-------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

#### Observations

- When reading parquet, more threads will spawn but only `cisfd` process takes the IO performance.
- Trying to tune parquet reader performance as described [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-parquet-reader/) but without any significant results.
- There is a big peak of egress data at the time of querying parquets from azure storage, that exceeds parquet data size several times. The parquets have ~300MB but the egress peak for *one read query* is about 2.5GB.

### Conclusion

- Reading parquets from Azure Files is for some reason slowed down to ridiculous speeds.
- Reading parquets from Azure Blob is even a bit slower.
- Reading parquets from local filesystem is nicely fast, but not suitable for real use.
- Reading CSV from any source utilizes storage throughput normally, therefore I assume some problem / misconfiguration of parquet reader.

### The questions

- What are the reasons that parquet read performance from Azure Storage is so drastically reduced?
- Is there way to optimize it?

Comment: have you attempted anything in databricks? I am noticing ridiculously poor performance when writing to blob-parquet from databricks data frame

Comment: facing same issue but with different use case. My application is reading 48 files with 1 MB each approx. First response from azure blob takes ~5 minutes, another request takes ~2 minutes to respond and gradually on later requests it takes around 400 milliseconds to respond. Is there anything related to caching ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would have cross checked IO performance issue using Azure Monitor and if the issue still persist, I would like to work closely on this issue. This may require a deeper investigation, so If you have a support plan, I request you file a support ticket, else please do let us know, we will try and help you get a one-time free technical support. In this case, could you send an email to AzCommunity[at]Microsoft[dot]com referencing this thread. Please mention "ATTN subm" in the subject field. Thank you for your cooperation on this matter and look forward to your reply.